# Get the key of a hash with a partial array value

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the key of a hash by matching against an array. Here is my hash:

```
hash = {
   "My Key" => ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

I can run the following code and get the key "My Key".

```
hash.key(["a", "b", "c"])
```

However, I want to be able to get the key by only supplying a portion of the array like this:

```
hash.key("a") #should return "My Key"
```

Is this possible with `.key`? If not, how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you do a lot of lookups on this structure? If so you may want to use `Set` to represent those arrays as tests are faster, or if this is really active, make an inverse lookup table.

Comment: @tadman I was thinking of an inverse lookup also, but that gets messy because the key then is an array and the key has to be checked for inclusion to see if the value exists... and there goes the speed.

Comment: @tasman yes I do

Comment: @theTinMan I mean expand that structure into `{ "a" => "My Key", "b" => "My Key", ... }` and so on, where that value is actually the same object so it's not as inefficient as it sounds. Like an *inverse plus flatten*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
hash = {
   'key1' => %w[a b c],
   'key2' => %w[d e f]
}
hash.find { |_, v| v.include?('e') }.first # => "key2"
```

Because you're trying to do a search for values containing a specific element, you can't really gain any speed using a reversed hash to do a lookup, which we'd usually do. Instead, by iterating over the hash we see an array of key/value pairs, which lets us look at the value, then find the one we want and then return just the associated key.

It is easy to iterate over that array of arrays ("AoA" because it's an array of arrays containing key/value pairs) using [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), peeking into the value's sub-arrays, then grabbing the returned key using [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-first).

This works because `Hash#find` returns the key and value:

```
hash.find { |k, v| k == 'key2' } # => ["key2", ["d", "e", "f"]]
hash.find { |k, v| v.include?('e') } # => ["key2", ["d", "e", "f"]]
```

[`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is important because it stops at the first occurrence found, which is about the best that can be done unless you know that every element in the sub-arrays are unique, in which case there are some tricks we can play with hash key/value pairs where multiple keys point to the same value. (Looking at @maxpleaner's answer, that's what he's suggesting.)

*IF* you find you need to locate the keys for multiple sub-arrays that have the target value:

```
hash = {
   'key1' => %w[a b c e],
   'key2' => %w[d e f]
}

hash.find_all { |_, v| v.include?('e') }.map(&:first) # => ["key1", "key2"]
```

That slows it down more because `find_all` will walk through the entire hash.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most explicit way of looping through your hash and find a matching key:

```
matching_key = hash.detect { |key, values| values.index("a") }
hash[matching_key]
```

Comment: `index` is an odd choice. Why not `include?`

Comment: Looping through a hash suffers from the same problem as looping through an array, all the speed is lost because it's treating the hash as a sequential access object, not a random access one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each value is only found in a single array (or just taking the last occurrence if there are duplicates), you can pre-compute these associations to enable O(1) instead of O(N) lookup:

```
keys_by_val = hash.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, vals)|
  vals.each do |val|
    memo[val] = key
  end
  memo
end
```

Then you can do `keys_by_val["a"]` to get `"My Key"`